# How can I call a method or a variable in switch statement from another case

Tags: java, arrays

How can I call a method or a variable in switch statement from another case
for example : 
case 0:
//I have a FOR loop in here to store int values in an ARRAY
case 1:
// here I want to print the values of the ARRAY from case 0

FYI:
the variables used in the FOR loop are all STATIC and the "i" variable that checks the length of the ARRAY is static too.
2- myRandomArray is not Static (I know it's an Object lol)

```
                case 0:
                    for(i = 0 ; i < myRandomArray.length ; i++)
                    {
                        myRandomArray[i] = myRandomObj.nextInt(MAXINT);                     
                    }
                break;
                case 1:
                        System.out.print(myRandomArray[i] + "  ");  
                break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically SWITCH allows to execute only one case at time. You can bring your Print block inside case 0 for loop itself.

```
       case 0:
            for(i = 0 ; i < myRandomArray.length ; i++)
            {
                myRandomArray[i] = myRandomObj.nextInt(MAXINT); 
                System.out.print(myRandomArray[i] + "  ");                     
            }
        break;
        case 1:
             ......

        break;
```

Comment: I want to print in CASE 1, not in the same case (CASE 0)....anyother suggestions?

Comment: Can i have the whole code block, where you declare myRandomArray

Comment: it's an assignment, do you want me to send it to you in the private?

Comment: Post the basic blocks, like declaration of myRandomArray & myRandomObj

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create a function and call it ?

```
    case 0:
        for(i = 0 ; i < myRandomArray.length ; i++)
        {
             myRandomArray[i] = myRandomObj.nextInt(MAXINT);
             Print(i);                     
        }
     break;
     case 1:
         Print(i - 1);
     break;
    .
    .
    .
}

private static void Print(int index){
    System.out.print(myRandomArray[index] + "  ");
}
```

Comment: the switch statment is inside a static Class, and I can't put the method "print()" neither in the same method Nor outside as a separate method...any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: @FouziMedfouni just add static to the method you create. Check my example again. Note that static functions can only use static variables. Since your variables are static you should be okay.

Comment: I tried it as the first resort lol, still giving an error (illegal start of an expression )

Comment: @FouziMedfouni you are not placing the `Print` method inside the method where the switch case is right ? you cant place a method inside a method lol.

Comment: hahhahhahaahahahhh yes thats exactly what I did lol .....now I have an exception lol                                                                  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: @FouziMedfouni thats because the index you probably send in case 1, is larger than the array content. you have to send a proper index.

Comment: hahhahhahaahahahhh yes thats exactly what I did lol .....now I have an exception lol                                                                  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 ........
I edited your method and turned it to 2 parameters method so I can pass myRandomArray since it was out of scope and not static (not sure if the instance of a class can be static or no :)

Comment: I sent "i" ....let me try something ...you want me to send you the source code to take a look at it

Comment: @FouziMedfouni try sending i - 1 you will print the last element of the array. I changed my example again.

Comment: MinilabReview.Print(myRandomArray.length, myRandomArray);

Comment: I don't want it to be print it in Case 0 though

Comment: @FouziMedfouni You print from where ever you want by placing the Print function. If you explain what you are trying to accomplish, perhaps I can help you better.

Comment: do you want me to send you the source code? and the example of the outcome?

Comment: may be this one will help:

    private static int returnMyArrayValue()
    {
        Random myRandomObj = new Random (mySeed);
        int []myRandomArray = new int [myInput];
        for(i = 0 ; i < myRandomArray.length ; i++)
        {
            myRandomArray[i] = myRandomObj.nextInt(MAXINT);
            System.out.print(myRandomArray[i] + "  ");                       
                        
        }
    return i ;}